# Ubuntu 13.04 suffers graphics corruption?

Tags: unity-dash

[image: Green speckled dash...?]

Ubuntu's dash turns green when I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04. I'm not sure what causes the problem, and I haven't found any similar problems.

I have included a screenshot so you can see for yourself.

Any solutions?

Comment: Open up `Terminal` and use these commands `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` and `unity --reset-icons`. See if that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, there was nothing wrong with my driver. I installed CompizConfig Settings Manager with

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

After I did that, I opened CompizConfig Settings Manager, and selected the Ubuntu Unity Plugin, and made sure that the background color was set to `#000000` and that Dash Blur was set to `No Blur`.

This should fix the problem, as it did for me.

I found my answer from [13.04 Dash bug](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139429) on Ubuntu Forums.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, hare is what I did:

- Install `Unity Tweak Tool` from Ubuntu Software Centre.
- In `Unity Tweak Tool` click on search button and deactivate background blur.

and that's it, everything is going to run OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with my nVidia graphic card on 12.10.

Go to System Settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers

and try to choose other option. It worked for me.