# Video card not working properly? (Greenish screen)

Tags: drivers, ati, video

I installed latest Ubuntu (13.04). If I check from system settings I get that Im using Galllium 0.4 drivers for RS690. I have an ATI card, ATI Radeon X1270...

Every time I open some window or ubuntu is trying to show me some kind of an effect, it hangs a lot. If I open launcher I get this as pictured above. I assume the grene things is transparency.

DO I need new drivers to be installed or what is the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to install new drivers. Proprietary drivers from AMD (fglrx) are not available for your X1270 any more (unless you go back to Ubuntu 8.04).

This is a known bug of Ubuntu 13.04 with RS690 graphic cards. However, there is a workaround. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286796/ubuntu-13-04-suffers-graphics-corruption) askubuntu post contains an answer. You have to disable Dash Blur with compiz-config-settings-manager or a similar application.
The Bug-report can be found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/1167018) on launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling proprietry drivers and use generic drivers.

Comment: Rebooting in safe graphic mode should verify that problem is in the drivers before actually disabling them.

Comment: He couldn't have installed proprietary drivers. (the combination Ubuntu 13.04 + fglrx + AMD RS690 (X1270) is impossible)